# Scoped enum is not raising a compiler error when passed to MAKEWPARAM. Why?

Tags: c++, enums, casting, visual-studio-2019

Can you please explain this one then for me?

We have this scoped `enum` definition:

```
enum class MenuNavigation : int {
    File,
    Edit,
    View,
    Options,
    Help
};
```

In my code I have places where it does this:

```
theApp.UpdateMenuBitmap(m_mapMenuBitmap, 
                        pView, 
                        MAKEWPARAM(MenuNavigation::View,5), IDB_BMP_MENU_ZOOM, true);
```

The key bit of that code is:

```
MAKEWPARAM(MenuNavigation::View,5)
```

I get no complication errors for this. We know that `MAKEWPARAM` is defined as:

```
#define MAKEWPARAM(l, h)      ((WPARAM)(DWORD)MAKELONG(l, h))
```

Now, I know that I can change my code like this:

```
MAKEWPARAM(to_underlying(MenuNavigation::View),5)
```

Where `to_underlying` is defined as:

```
template <typename E>
constexpr auto to_underlying(E e) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>(e);
}
```

But why did the compiler not complain about needing a static cast in the first instance?

## Update

`MAKELONG` is defined as:

```
#define MAKELONG(a, b)      ((LONG)(((WORD)(((DWORD_PTR)(a)) & 0xffff)) | ((DWORD)((WORD)(((DWORD_PTR)(b)) & 0xffff))) << 16))
```

Comment: How is `MAKELONG` defined?

Comment: @Eljay I have added the definition for `MAKELONG` to the question.

Comment: These macros are part of the Win API, are they not? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-makewparam Are you asking about their implementation or how they are supposed to be used? I think it would be a good idea for you to clarify that in your question. If you are asking about their use, then their implementation shouldn't matter.

Comment: @walnut I thought my question was clear. I was passing a scoped `enum` and the compiler was not complaining that it needed casting. But as someone has answered, these macros actual perform a cast on the values and this is why it is OK.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I am not that familiar with the Win API, but just because it works with a given current implementation usually does not mean that it is allowed/documented behavior that one may rely on. I was getting at that difference, but if the answer answers your question, fine with me.

Comment: @walnut So what are you saying? Use `MAKEWAPARM(to_underlying...), 5)`?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I don't know how these macros are supposed to be used. I was just suggesting a possible improvement of the question that I noticed. No need to follow that suggestion if you don't see an issue.

Comment: Using `to_underlying` won't give you any benefit. Using that macro is not type safe and it is your responsability to ensure that the underlying type is not too wide (i.e 64 bits) and that both side of the message use the same type (cast back to original type)

Comment: Does `UpdateMenuBitmap` is your own function? Is so, then it is clearly a bad design if you need to use `MAKEWPARAM` at every call site (instead of having a function that take one extra argument). And if not, it might be a good idea to have an inline wrapper anyway. And by the way, an hard-coded value like `5` in code is also a code smell.

Comment: @Phil1970 It is more of a fudge. Most menu items can be accessed by there menu item ID. But not the flyout menus. I have to use the position on that menu. Since I have a single array of bitmaps I needed a solution for adding multiple images that were both at the same position on different menus. I used "5" but I can easily create a constant. And yes, I could add an extra parameter to my `UpdateMenuBitmap` method too.

Comment: @Phil1970 The reason I did it that way is because the function `void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::UpdateMenuBitmap(MenuBitmapsMap& rMapMenuBitmap, CMenu* pMenu, UINT uCommandID, UINT uBMPResource, bool bByPosition /*false*/, bool bDisabled /*false*/)` is used in nearly 100 places in my software. I don't want to change them all. I could add it to the end witha  default value I suppose. But that is going off topic.

Comment: @Phil1970 Out of 87 calls, only 4 of them needed to use MAKEWPARAM. All the others just take a menu resource ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are doing a `cast` in the first instance. When you do

```
(type)value
```

you are doing a `static_cast`.

In fact, using a [c-style cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) like that means that the compiler will attempt to do a

1. `const_cast`
2. `static_cast`,
3. `static_cast` + `const_cast`
4. `reinterpret_cast`
5. `reinterpret_cast` + `const_cast`

This is pretty unsafe in most cases, so I would suggest always explicitly saying `static_cast` when that's all you want.

Comment: The various `MAKE` macros are provided by Microsoft as part of Visual Studio.